# Most Pythonic and efficient way to insert character at end of string if not already there

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

```
b = 'week'
```

I want to check if the last character is an "s". If not, append an "s".

Is there a Pythonic one-liner for this one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
b = b + 's' if not b.endswith('s') else b
```

Personally, I'd still stick with two lines, however:

```
if not b.endswith('s'):
    b += 's'
```

Comment: Why not both? :) `b += 's' if not b.endswith('s') else ''`

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way possible:

```
b = b.rstrip('s') + 's'
```

But I would write like this:

```
b = ''.join((b.rstrip('s'), 's'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def pluralize(string):
    if string:
        if string[-1] != 's':
            string += 's'

    return string
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but in one line you could write:

```
b = '%ss' % b.rstrip('s')
```

Example

```
>>> string = 'week'
>>> b = '%ss' % string.rstrip('s')
>>> b
'weeks'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = b + 's' if b[-1:] != 's' else b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def add_s_if_not_already_there (string):
     return string + 's' * (1 - string.endswith('s'))
```

I would still stick with the two liner but I like how 'arithmetic' this feels.